# java quiz only accessing constructor

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create a 10 multiple choice question quiz using arrays. I'm extremely new so bear with me. I'm currently able to get a window to populate, with the title, and the buttons I have set. The buttons don't do anything, and the questions with choices are not populating. It seems as when I call the class to the main method it's only calling the constructor. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. I have an array for my questions with the choices, and array that has the question and the correct answer. Please help. I been working on this for 4 days.

1st file sets data:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{
   JPanel panel;
   JPanel panelresult;
   JRadioButton choice1;
   JRadioButton choice2;
   JRadioButton choice3;
   JRadioButton choice4;
   ButtonGroup bg;
   JLabel question;
   JButton next;
   String[][] questions;
   String[][] choices;
   int qaid;
   HashMap<Integer,String>map;

   public Test2()
   {

      setTitle("Tennis Quiz");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(430,350);
      setLocation(300,100);
      setResizable(false);
      Container cont = getContentPane();
      cont.setLayout(null);
      cont.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
      bg = new ButtonGroup();
      choice1 = new JRadioButton("A");
      choice2 = new JRadioButton("B");
      choice3 = new JRadioButton("C");
      choice4 = new JRadioButton("D");
      bg.add(choice1);
      bg.add(choice2);
      bg.add(choice3);
      bg.add(choice4);
      question = new JLabel("Choose a correct answer");
      question.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
      question.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD, 11));
      next = new JButton("Next");
      next.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      panel.setLocation(10,10);
      panel.setSize(400,300);
      panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));
      panel.add(question);
      panel.add(choice1);
      panel.add(choice2);
      panel.add(choice3);
      panel.add(choice4);
      panel.add(next);
      cont.add(panel);
      setVisible(true);
      qaid = 0;
      setData();

      String readqaId = readqaId(qaid);                  
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       switch (next.getText()) {
           case "Next":
               if(qaid<9)
               {
                   map.put(qaid,getSelection());
                   qaid++;
                   readqaId(qaid);
               }
               else
               {
                   map.put(qaid,getSelection());
                   next.setText("Show answers");
               }      break;
           case "Show answers":

               break;
       }
   }

   public String setData()
   {
      questions = new String[10][5];

      questions[0][0] = "Who is world's number one on the ATP Tennis tour?";
      questions[0][1] = "Del Potro";
      questions[0][2] = "Nadal";
      questions[0][3] = "Djockovic";
      questions[0][4] = "Federer";

      questions[1][0] = "Who is world's number one on the WTA Tennis tour?";
      questions[1][1] = "Venus Williams";
      questions[1][2] = "Serenca Williams";
      questions[1][3] = "Simona Halep";
      questions[1][4] = "Svetlana Kuznetsova";

      questions[2][0] = "Who has the fastest serve?";
      questions[2][1] = "Andy Roddick";
      questions[2][2] = "Milos Roanic";
      questions[2][3] = "Leyton Hewitt";
      questions[2][4] = "Juan Martin Del Potro";

      questions[3][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the mens tour?";
      questions[3][1] = "Roger Federer";
      questions[3][2] = "Raphael Nadal";
      questions[3][3] = "Novak Djokovack";
      questions[3][4] = "Andy Murray";

      questions[4][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the womens tour?";
      questions[4][1] = "Chris Evert";
      questions[4][2] = "Billie Jean King";
      questions[4][3] = "Martina Navratilova";
      questions[4][4] = "Serena Williams";

     questions[5][0] = "Which male tennis player has won the most majors?";
     questions[5][1] = "Donald Young?";
     questions[5][2] = "Raphal Nadal?";
     questions[5][3] = "Roger Federer?";
     questions[5][4] = "Pete Sampras";

     questions[6][0] = "Which male tennis player won the U.S. Open in 2014";
     questions[6][1] = "Roger Federer";
     questions[6][2] = "Lleyton Hewitt";
     questions[6][3] = "Rafael Nadal";
     questions[6][4] = "Marian Celic";

     questions[7][0] = "Which female tennis player has won all 4 Grand Slams?";
     questions[7][1] = "Venus Williams";
     questions[7][2] = "Svetlana Kuznetsova";
     questions[7][3] = "Caroline Wozniacki";
     questions[7][4] = "Serena Williams"; 

     questions[8][0] = "Which male tennis player won the French Open in 2014";
     questions[8][1] = "Roger Federer";
     questions[8][2] = "Raphael Nadal";
     questions[8][3] = "Milos Roanic";
     questions[8][4] = "Gael Monfils";

     questions[9][0] = "Which female tennis player won the French Open in 2014?";
     questions[9][1] = "Venus Williams";
     questions[9][2] = "Serena Williams";
     questions[9][3] = "Caroline Wozniacki";
     questions[9][4] = "Maria Sharapova";

     choices = new String[10][2];
     choices[0][0] = "Who is world's number one on the ATP Tennis tour?";
     choices[0][3] = "Djockovic";

     choices[1][0] = "Who is world's number one on the WTA Tennis tour?";
     choices[1][2] = "Serenca Williams";

     choices[2][0] =  "Who has the fastest serve?";
     choices[2][2] = "Milos Roanic";

     choices[3][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the mens tour?";
     choices[3][1] = "Roger Federer";

     choices[4][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the womens tour?";
     choices[4][3] = "Martina Navratilova";

     choices[5][0] = "Which male tennis player has won the most majors?";
     choices[5][3] = "Roger Federer?";

     choices[6][0] = "Which male tennis player won the U.S. Open in 2014";
     choices[6][4] =  "Marian Celic";

     choices[7][0] = "Which female tennis player has won all 4 Grand Slams?";
     choices[7][4] = "Serena Williams"; 

     choices[8][0]= "Which male tennis player won the French Open in 2014";
     choices[8][2] = "Raphael Nadal";

     choices[9][0] = "Which female tennis player won the French Open in 2014?"; 
     choices[9][4] = "Maria Sharapova";

    map = new HashMap<>();
    return null;        
 }

 public String getSelection()
 {
    String selectedChoice = null;
    Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons=bg.getElements();
    while(buttons.hasMoreElements())
    {
       JRadioButton temp = (JRadioButton)buttons.nextElement();
       if(temp.isSelected())
       {
          selectedChoice = temp.getText();
       }
    }
    return(selectedChoice); 
 }

 private String readqaId(int qaid)
 {
    question.setText("" + questions[qaid][0]);
    choice1.setText(choices[qaid][1]);
    choice2.setText(choices[qaid][2]);
    choice3.setText(choices[qaid][3]);
    choice4.setText(choices[qaid][4]);
    choice1.setSelected(true);
    return null;        
 }

 public void reset()
 {
   qaid = 0;
   map.clear();
   readqaId(qaid);
   next.setText("Next");
 }

 public int calCorrectAnswer()
 {
   int qnum = 10;
   int count = 0;
   for(int qid = 0; qid<qnum;qid++)
   if(choices[qid][1].equals(map.get(qid)))
       count++;
   return count;
 }

 public class Report extends JFrame
 {
    Report()
    {
       setTitle("Answers");
       setSize(850,550);
       setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
               {
                  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                  {
                      dispose();
                      reset();
                  }
                  });
                Draw d = new Draw();
                add(d);
                setVisible(true);
               }
    class Draw extends Canvas
    {
       public void paint(Graphics g)
       {
          int qnum = 10;
          int x = 10;
          int y = 20;
          for(int i = 0; i<qnum;i++)
          {
             g.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD, 12));
             g.drawString(i+1+"." + choices[i][0], x, y);
             y+=30;
             g.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.PLAIN, 12));
             g.drawString("Correct Answer"+choices[i][1], x, y);
             y+=30;
             g.drawString(" Your answer" + map.get(i), x, y);
             y+=30;
             if(y>400)
             {
             y = 20;
             x = 450;
             }


          }
          int numc=calCorrectAnswer();
          g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
          g.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD,14));
          g.drawString("Number of correct answers." + numc, 300, 500);

       }
    }
    }
 }
```

2nd file pulls first file:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class QuizProgram
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Test2 test2 = new Test2();
   }

}
```

Comment: I have called the method setData() instead of variable, and removed question 10 that is outside the array parameters. My call to method is advising over ride able method in constructor. Still does not display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some problems :

1. You are not calling `setData` method, so you are not initializing your arrays. Instead, you are declaring a variable of the same name - `String setData;`
2. If you did call `setData`, you'd get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcpetion, since an array of 10 elements only has indices from 0 to 9. You should init your arrays properly : `questions = new String[11][5];` and `choices = new String[11][2];`. Either that, or you should remove one question.
3. You also have an error in readqaId. You take the choices from the wrong array.

It should be:

```
private String readqaId(int qaid)
{
    question.setText("" + questions[qaid][0]);
    choice1.setText(questions[qaid][1]);
    choice2.setText(questions[qaid][2]);
    choice3.setText(questions[qaid][3]);
    choice4.setText(questions[qaid][4]);
    choice1.setSelected(true);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I removed question 10. How would I call my setData instead of declaring it a variable?

Comment: @New2Java `setData()`. BTW, it doesn't look like you need the return value of that method, so you can change it to void.

Comment: when I call setData(), I'm getting overridable method in constructor. I changed setData() to void. Unfortunately still not displaying setData() on the pane. Sorry this is where I'm completely stumped.

Comment: @New2Java I made another edit. I suggest you run your code in a debugger and see what's getting called.

Answer (score 3):

you defined

```
      questions = new String[10][5];
```

and then

```
     questions[10][0] = "What size is a tennis ball?";
     questions[10][1] = "2.57 - 2.70 inches";
     questions[10][2] = "3 - 4 inches";
     questions[10][3] = "1 - 2 inches";
     questions[10][4] = "5-6 inches";
```

you can not access index 10 of questions while defining it with length 10.

Comment: I agree. When you define an array in java, the value is the number of items and not the max index, so if you define 10 they will be 0 to 9. You have 11 questions, remove one or change definition.