# user input choice not recognized

Tags: java, arrays

I previously posted a question and now my pane displays the question and choices a-d. When user selects choice and clicks next there is no action. I want the user to choose their option, click next, have the quiz display "correct" or "incorrect", and move to the next answer. I believe my error is in the actionPeformed() method or the getSelection() method.  I had to also create a new method with an array to provide the answers. I tried running debugger and getting no variables to display.  Not sure how I made a mess of the code as I thought it would run as expected. Please help. If interested previous post can be found at [java quiz only accessing constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103388/java-quiz-only-accessing-constructor/27103455?noredirect=1#comment42711387_27103455)

First file

```
class Test2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panelresult;
    JRadioButton choice1;
    JRadioButton choice2;
    JRadioButton choice3;
    JRadioButton choice4;
    ButtonGroup bg;
    JLabel question;
    JButton next;
    String[][] questions;
    String[][] choices;
    int qaid;

    HashMap<Integer, String> map;

    public Test2() {

        setTitle("Tennis Quiz");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(430, 350);
        setLocation(300, 100);
        setResizable(false);
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(null);
        cont.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        bg = new ButtonGroup();
        choice1 = new JRadioButton("A");
        choice2 = new JRadioButton("B");
        choice3 = new JRadioButton("C");
        choice4 = new JRadioButton("D");
        bg.add(choice1);
        bg.add(choice2);
        bg.add(choice3);
        bg.add(choice4);
        question = new JLabel("Choose a correct answer");
        question.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        question.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD, 11));
        next = new JButton("Next");
        next.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.setLocation(10, 10);
        panel.setSize(400, 300);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
        panel.add(question);
        panel.add(choice1);
        panel.add(choice2);
        panel.add(choice3);
        panel.add(choice4);
        panel.add(next);
        cont.add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setData();
        qaid = 0;
        readqaId(qaid);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (next.getText()) {
        case "Next":
            if (qaid < 9) {
                map.put(qaid, getSelection());
                qaid++;
                readqaId(qaid);
            } else {
                map.put(qaid, getSelection());
                next.setText("Show answers");
            }
            break;
        case "Show answers":

            break;
        }
    }

    public void setData() {
        questions = new String[10][5];

        questions[0][0] = "Who is world's number one on the ATP Tennis tour?";
        questions[0][1] = "Del Potro";
        questions[0][2] = "Nadal";
        questions[0][3] = "Djockovic";
        questions[0][4] = "Federer";

        questions[1][0] = "Who is world's number one on the WTA Tennis tour?";
        questions[1][1] = "Venus Williams";
        questions[1][2] = "Serenca Williams";
        questions[1][3] = "Simona Halep";
        questions[1][4] = "Svetlana Kuznetsova";

        questions[2][0] = "Who has the fastest serve?";
        questions[2][1] = "Andy Roddick";
        questions[2][2] = "Milos Roanic";
        questions[2][3] = "Leyton Hewitt";
        questions[2][4] = "Juan Martin Del Potro";

        questions[3][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the mens tour?";
        questions[3][1] = "Roger Federer";
        questions[3][2] = "Raphael Nadal";
        questions[3][3] = "Novak Djokovack";
        questions[3][4] = "Andy Murray";

        questions[4][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the womens tour?";
        questions[4][1] = "Chris Evert";
        questions[4][2] = "Billie Jean King";
        questions[4][3] = "Martina Navratilova";
        questions[4][4] = "Serena Williams";

        questions[5][0] = "Which male tennis player has won the most majors?";
        questions[5][1] = "Donald Young?";
        questions[5][2] = "Raphal Nadal?";
        questions[5][3] = "Roger Federer?";
        questions[5][4] = "Pete Sampras";

        questions[6][0] = "Which male tennis player won the U.S. Open in 2014";
        questions[6][1] = "Roger Federer";
        questions[6][2] = "Lleyton Hewitt";
        questions[6][3] = "Rafael Nadal";
        questions[6][4] = "Marian Celic";

        questions[7][0] = "Which female tennis player has won all 4 Grand Slams?";
        questions[7][1] = "Venus Williams";
        questions[7][2] = "Svetlana Kuznetsova";
        questions[7][3] = "Caroline Wozniacki";
        questions[7][4] = "Serena Williams";

        questions[8][0] = "Which male tennis player won the French Open in 2014";
        questions[8][1] = "Roger Federer";
        questions[8][2] = "Raphael Nadal";
        questions[8][3] = "Milos Roanic";
        questions[8][4] = "Gael Monfils";

        questions[9][0] = "Which female tennis player won the French Open in 2014?";
        questions[9][1] = "Venus Williams";
        questions[9][2] = "Serena Williams";
        questions[9][3] = "Caroline Wozniacki";
        questions[9][4] = "Maria Sharapova";

        map = new HashMap<>();

    }

    public void answerKey() {
        choices = new String[10][2];
        choices[0][0] = "Who is world's number one on the ATP Tennis tour?";
        choices[0][3] = "Djockovic";

        choices[1][0] = "Who is world's number one on the WTA Tennis tour?";
        choices[1][2] = "Serenca Williams";

        choices[2][0] = "Who has the fastest serve?";
        choices[2][2] = "Milos Roanic";

        choices[3][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the mens tour?";
        choices[3][1] = "Roger Federer";

        choices[4][0] = "Who holds the most titles on the womens tour?";
        choices[4][3] = "Martina Navratilova";

        choices[5][0] = "Which male tennis player has won the most majors?";
        choices[5][3] = "Roger Federer?";

        choices[6][0] = "Which male tennis player won the U.S. Open in 2014";
        choices[6][4] = "Marian Celic";

        choices[7][0] = "Which female tennis player has won all 4 Grand Slams?";
        choices[7][4] = "Serena Williams";

        choices[8][0] = "Which male tennis player won the French Open in 2014";
        choices[8][2] = "Raphael Nadal";

        choices[9][0] = "Which female tennis player won the French Open in 2014?";
        choices[9][4] = "Maria Sharapova";
    }

    public String getSelection() {
        String selectedChoice = null;
        Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = bg.getElements();
        while (buttons.hasMoreElements()) {
            JRadioButton temp = (JRadioButton) buttons.nextElement();
            if (temp.isSelected()) {
                selectedChoice = temp.getText();
            }
        }
        return (selectedChoice);
    }

    private String readqaId(int qaid) {
        question.setText("" + questions[qaid][0]);
        choice1.setText(questions[qaid][1]);
        choice2.setText(questions[qaid][2]);
        choice3.setText(questions[qaid][3]);
        choice4.setText(questions[qaid][4]);
        choice1.setSelected(true);
        return null;

    }

    public void reset() {
        qaid = 0;
        map.clear();
        readqaId(qaid);
        next.setText("Next");
    }

    public int calCorrectAnswer() {
        int qnum = 10;
        int count = 0;
        for (int qaid = 0; qaid < qnum; qaid++)
            if (choices[qaid][1].equals(map.get(qaid)))
                count++;
        return count;
    }

    public class Report extends JFrame {
        Report() {
            setTitle("Answers");
            setSize(850, 550);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    dispose();
                    reset();
                }
            });
            Draw d = new Draw();
            add(d);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        class Draw extends Canvas {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                int qnum = 10;
                int x = 10;
                int y = 20;
                for (int i = 0; i < qnum; i++) {
                    g.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD, 12));
                    g.drawString(i + 1 + "." + choices[i][0], x, y);
                    y += 30;
                    g.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                    g.drawString("Correct Answer" + choices[i][1], x, y);
                    y += 30;
                    g.drawString(" Your answer" + map.get(i), x, y);
                    y += 30;
                    if (y > 400) {
                        y = 20;
                        x = 450;
                    }

                }
                int numc = calCorrectAnswer();
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.setFont(new Font("Aria", Font.BOLD, 14));
                g.drawString("Number of correct answers." + numc, 300, 500);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

2nd file

```
public class QuizProgram
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Test2 test2 = new Test2();

   }

}
```

Comment: What was your question again?

Comment: have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: @user1438038 why is user input not not be recognized. When they choose their answer A, B, C, or D. I have a button for them to click "Next". When you click "next" nothing happens. It doesn't move to the next question or confirms if their selection is right or wrong.

Comment: @jhamon - I ran the debugger and it advises no variable found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class Test2 implements ActionListener, but I don't see any code that registers the listener.

I'm guessing your intention is that actionPerformed() be called when the user clicks the Next button. In which case your code should have the following line after the Next button is created:

```
next.addActionListener(this);
```

("this" being Test2, which is your ActionListener.)

Comment: David answered first, FYI. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You create a button but never add an ActionListener.
Try this:

```
next = new JButton("Next");
next.addActionListener(this);
```

(I'm assuming Test2 is the ActionListener you want to use)